# Need to implement WYSIWYG editor on Android

Tags: android, editor, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

Basically, i am trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor just like MS Word or Quick Office. After so much R & D, i am not able to find a good simple solution.,The app would contain basic formatting buttons like text style, font, size, alignment, bullets.,.
So please anyone suggest something

I am adding snapshots from QuickOffice.,It is WYSIWIG Rich Text editor.
Snapshots are in a Series from 1 to 5.,.Pleas go through them..,.I am sure you will understand what i want now.,.

[image: Default Text Editor With formatting options above]

[image: Some text typed and format button clicked to show options]

[image: Bold button clicked]

[image: some text typed in bold and clicked format button again and clicked bold button again]

[image: Typing in normal style]

Comment: Rahul can you write down specifically what suggestion you are looking for?

Comment: Did you mean, you want to do something like Google Docs/Drive word editor? I think `Spannable` (and `SpannableString`) is a good starting point...

Comment: Requirement is basically a rich text editor on android platform,.,. Basically WYSIWYG means What You See is What You Get,.So this app would be having format buttons like bold italics underline, so when Bold is clicked, the text will appear bold from that point on,, but in the background the text would contain tags, like a markdown editor

Answer (score 6):

Rahul I got the point. Thanks for your explanation.
You have to build the listener what you are looking for any button's action. Like bold the text, underline , changing the color or font, change the justification of text and others. I will prefer to follow these link from where you will get depth knowledge of working with text editor on android:

GOOGLE DRIVE SDK [ANDROID, iOS , Java & more platform]

https://github.com/googledrive/dredit

Some other repository you can check :

https://github.com/paulmach/Text-Edit-for-Android

https://github.com/jecelyin/920-Text-Editor

https://github.com/jiro-aqua/Jota-Text-Editor

And if you get any specific problem you can share I will try to give the solution.

Happy coding !!!

[image: Android notepad where you can write document using some excellent feature like font selection, color selection, left,right & middle justification and more nice feature]